# Why template reference variable using ngModel is undefined inside a for-loop?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I'am trying to get a DOM element in HTML template to disable/enable a 
form-button based on input value and using `ngModel`:**`#Custom_FirstName="ngModel"`**. The input is a custom field in separated component.

My issue is that the element `Custom_FirstName` is always `undefined` and I found out that it has to do with the For Loop `ngFor`. When I remove `ngFor`, The error is fixed. But this would not solve my issue because I need the for-loop as the user can add more than one input-text and user with `firstName` dynamically.

**Code:**

```
<div *ngFor="let el of users.departments.admins; let i=index; trackBy: trackByFn"
    <input-text [name]="'firstanme'"                                                             
                [(ngModel)]="el.firstName"                                                          
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"                                                      
                [readonly]="false"                                                           
                [required]="true"
                labelText="First Name"
                #Custom_FirstName="ngModel">
    </input-text>
</div>
```

**Button:**

`<button [disabled]="!Custom_FirstName.value || ....>`

I have been checking the [official Doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), but I was not able to find the fix for that. Any hint how work around this issue?

Comment: Don't you consider using reactive form instead of template form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation [says](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variable-considerations):

> The scope of a reference variable is the entire template. So, don't
>   define the same variable name more than once in the same template as
>   the runtime value will be unpredictable.

Since you already have bound input with data just track the data. Add to your component:

```
hasEmptyValue() {
    return users.departments.admins
        .some(admin => !admin.firstName || admin.firstName.length===0);
}
```

And make changes in template:

```
<button [disabled]="hasEmptyValue() || ....>
```

Comment: Thanks. But where does `admin` comes from? I think you mean `admins` plural.
`!admin.firstName || admin.firstName.length===0`. And also the IDE shows following error: "Property length does not exists on type 'boolean'"

Comment: And if I would use this to have different variables based on the index, it also doesn't work. `#Custom_FirstName[i]="ngModel"`

Comment: @k.vincent `admin` is a parameter of function we passed to `some()`. And first edition of an answer had an error. `some()` returns a `boolean`. So it definitely doesn't need `lenght`. I've corrected the code.

Comment: @k.vincent concerning your question about where `admin` comes from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Working fine. Great. One question please, When I sue same function twice for 2 different fields/elements as 2 different separated functions, it works/trigger for the first one but not for the second. Example
`<button [disabled]="fieladXhasEmptyValue() || fieladYhasEmptyValue>`. 
`FieldXhasEmptyValue() {
    return users.departments.fieldX
        .some(admin => !admin.fieldX || admin.fieldX.length===0);
}` `FieldYhasEmptyValue() {
    return users.departments.fieldY
        .some(admin => !admin.fieldY || admin.fieldY.length===0);
}`

Comment: @k.vincent didn't you forget specify brackets after `fieladYhasEmptyValue` in template? Like `fieladYhasEmptyValue()`. Because you have to call it as a function.

Comment: Yes, true. But it's just a typo here. In my code it's correct. I call it with brackets. Anyway, Now it's working fine also when using 2 function with same idea.
As the second field in my code is an array too. So it means array within another array. Documentation Mozilla is good. Thumps up.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, template reference variables are scoped to the template they are defined in. So basically you can only use each `#Custom_FirstName` inside the `div` with `*ngFor` and not outside of it. If you don't use `*ngFor` the scope increase to the whole document so you don't get `undefined`.

To solve your problem I suggest that you wrap your code in a `<form>` tag and get a template reference of the form and check the validity of the form for disabling the button:

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let el of users.departments.admins; let i=index; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <input-text [name]="'firstanme'"                                                             
                [(ngModel)]="el.firstName"                                                    
                [readonly]="false"                                                           
                [required]="true"
                labelText="First Name">
    </input-text>
  </div>
</form>
```

And your button will be:

```html
<button [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
```

Also, make sure to add `FormsModule` to your module imports.

Comment: This won't work because I have to use `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` Anyway I did give it a try. No chance.

Comment: @k.vincent Ah yes, if you need the standalone option, it won't work!